# Is reverse debugging possible?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering

I know there are some products for reverse debugging.

I am wondering that does reverse debugging mean going to one step back or starting over again up to one step back?

I've found an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535497).

Comment: I can't tell you if it means "really debugging backwards" because I don't know what *you mean by* "really debugging backwards" ;-)

Comment: @delnan: He means "does it reverse the previous step or does it run from the beginning with a virtual breakpoint on the previous line."

Comment: Reverse debugging is putting the bugs back in.

Comment: Are you thinking of the [omniscient debugger](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does reverse debugging mean going to one step back or starting over again up to one step back?

According to the link you posted, "reverse debugging" means being able to undo instructions in the debugger. So you'd have something like a 'step back' command that tells the debugger to reverse the effect of the last instruction executed. It doesn't mean re-running the program to get back to the previous instruction.